# java: symbol lookup error: java: undefined symbol: JLI_StringDup in conda environment

Tags: java, linux, anaconda

Running anything with java (even just the java command on its own) yields the error:

`java: symbol lookup error: java: undefined symbol: JLI_StringDup`

I am in a conda environment with java-jdk and openjdk installed.
OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server, version 7.9.

I believe that this JLI_StringDup might have something to do with libjli, so I tried adding paths to LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH and even PATH (cause why not) to no avail:

```
PATH=$PATH:<conda-env>/lib/jvm/lib
LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/lib/jvm/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/lib/jvm/lib
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/lib/jvm/lib

PATH=$PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib
LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib

PATH=$PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib/amd64/jli
LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib/amd64/jli
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib/amd64/jli
JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<conda-env>/jre/lib/amd64/jli

java
```

Where  is the path to my conda environment, and it returns:

`java: symbol lookup error: java: undefined symbol: JLI_StringDup`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue and I'm posting in case others encounter the same. This seemed to be due to some conflict between openjdk and java-jdk conda packages. I solved it by:

```
conda install --force-reinstall java-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by simply removing java-jdk using:

```
conda remove java-jdk
```